# Transformations of the plane that conserve alignment

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm trying to get a grasp on transformations of the plane that conserve alignment of points (that is, the images of aligned points are aligned).

In Cartesian coordinates, I'm interested in functions $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ such that if $f(a_x,a_y)=(A_x,A_y)$, $f(b_x,b_y)=(B_x,B_y)$, $f(c_x,c_y)=(C_x,C_y)$, and $(b_x-a_x)(c_y-a_y)=(c_x-a_x)(b_y-a_y)$, then $(B_x-A_x)(C_y-A_y)=(C_x-A_x)(B_y-A_y)$.

I'm sure these functions have a name [update: I now guess [collineations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation), but I'm far from sure], which would help! And if that's not asking too much:

- How many real parameters do I need to characterize one? My bets are <strike>on 6</strike> [update: now on 8; affine transforms seem to be only a subclass of what I seek].
- What's the general algebraic form of the transformation from $(a_x,a_y)$ to $(A_x,A_y)$?

Please lead me in the right direction!

Comment: Any affine transformation of the form $f(v) = A v + b$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, and $b$ is a $2 \times 1$ vector, satisfies the given condition.  So your guess is correct, you can specify the transformation by choosing the $4$ elements of $A$ and the two elements of $b$, arbitrarily, making a total of six parameters.

Comment: @Hosam Hajjir: my transformations  _include_ affine transformations, but turn out to be  more general. See update.

Comment: Projective transformations $x'=(ax+by+c)/(gx+hy+k),y'=(dx+ey+f)/(gx+hy+k)$ if you accept that a whole line hasn't any image... which indeed rely on $8$ parameters (due to homogeneity)

Comment: @Jean Marie: Thanks a lot, that's what I was after. Indeed, I have to exclude a line of the plane from the input domain, except for affine transformations. I'm sure I studied that a long time ago, but have not used it in decades.

Answer (score 0):

This expand Jean Marie's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8884230).

Transformations of the plane that preserve lines are [collineations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation). They include [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), and other functions which are undefined on a line; we can fix this y including $\infty$ in the destination set.

The analytical expression of the coordinates $(x',y')$ of a collineation as a function of the coordinates $(x,y)$ of it's input can be put as $x'=(a\,x+b\,y+c)/(g\,x+h\,y+1)$ and $y'=(d\,x+e\,y+f)/(g\,x+h\,y+1)$, with 8 real parameters. The affine case is $g=h=0$. For other cases, points on the line $g\,x+h\,y+1=0$ have no image.